# Windows Server 2008R2 / IIS 7.5 VM Open Ports

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall, iis-7.5, windows-firewall

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7.5 server Hyper-v VM which when I run NMAP shows a lot of open ports.

This server acts as a web server running Wordpress sites so it also needs MySQL.

I am thinking the only ports open should be 80, 443 for IIS, and 3306 + 3389 for MySQL / RDP which I have tied to my static IP for remote access.

Is it safe for me to close all other ports or does Hyper-V / Win Server need certain ports open?

Answer (score 1):

There are going to be a number of ports open, but if those ports aren't exposed to the internet, meaning you have a network firewall in front of the server and only allow inbound HTTP, HTTPS, etc. to reach the server, then you may not want to go through the exercise of "hardening" the server. If you do want to "harden" the server then my suggestion would be to run the SCW (Security Configuration Wizard).